# Quasar q-select makes an extra select?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar's q-select like this:

```
<q-select ref="search_shares" dense use-input v-model="search_model" :options="quick_search" @filter="quick_search_search" @input="open_sharelink" v-if="Quasar.Screen.gt.md == true">
    <template v-slot:append v-if="search_model != ''">
        <q-icon name="mdi-magnify"></q-icon>
    </template>
</q-select>
```

For some reason, it creates an EXTRA select box when focused. It works, but I'd prefer not having an extra box...or is this default behaviour?

[image: Screenshot showing 2 search boxes]

Thanks in advance

Comment: why can't u go with vuesax?

Comment: Thank you, but that's not an answer. I'm not using Vuesax, I'm using Quasar and that is that. Vuesax might be great, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Try to make a minimal example in CodePen. Or post the whole code, including the JavaScript code. Is important to analyze all events and options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is default behavior in mobile mode.

checkout this issue

Reference: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/4007

---

**UPDATE**

looks like quasar added a props to customize the mode

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#Options-list-display-mode

but there is a warning mentioned that ios might break with menu mode